# What does "SiO2 scale" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

The SiO<sub>2</sub> scale was so thin that it was not detected in SEM cross sections.

Comment: Silicon dioxide, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it is silicon dioxide but I need the meaning of scale in this context.

Comment: I don't see an ELL question here.  It seems to be about chemistry.  There is no reason to suppose a non-chemist would be able to understand this, and every reason to suppose a chemist would understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si02 is of course the chemical formula for Silicon dioxide/ It can form a thin skin or overlay on a surface, which is known as a "scale" This may be by analogy with a fish scale, or it may have some other origin, I haven't checked.

[Oxford languages](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/scale) gives the following relevant senses:

> 3. A flaky covering or deposit. ‘If left untreated, the scale may become thick, yellow and greasy and, occasionally, secondary bacterial
>    infection may occur.’
>
>    3.1 A white deposit formed in a kettle, boiler, etc. by the evaporation of water containing lime.
>    ‘banging sounds emanating from the boiler may be caused by a buildup of scale’
>
> ...
>
> ```
> 3.3 A coating of oxide formed on heated metal. 
> ‘a spray-on chemical for removing welding scale and heat discoloration from stainless steel’
> ```

Answer (score 1):

'Scale' can be a name for a thin layer of other matter adhering to some material, often metal, after hot processing. It consists mainly of oxides produced by chemical reaction between the hot material and air. For example, 'mill scale' is found on freshly rolled steel, and so is SiO<sub>2</sub> (silica) scale:

> Mill scale, often shortened to just scale, is the flaky surface of hot
> rolled steel, consisting of the mixed iron oxides iron(II) oxide
> (FeO), iron(III) oxide (Fe2O3), and iron(II,III) oxide (Fe3O4,
> magnetite).
>
> Mill scale is formed on the outer surfaces of plates, sheets or
> profiles when they are being produced by rolling red hot iron or steel
> billets in rolling mills ... It is usually less than 0.1 mm (0.0039 in) thick, and
> initially adheres to the steel surface and protects it from atmospheric corrosion
> provided no break occurs in this coating.

[Mill Scale (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_scale)

> The cast material exhibited three regimes of behavior. Above 1000°C a
> continuous protective silica scale formed. Between 600 and 1000°C a
> silica scale formed, but formation of silica within grain boundaries,
> which are believed to be cracked, was observed.

[Oxidation of MoSi2 and comparison with other silicide materials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/092150939290324T)